# Product Schedule Update magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can I check if a product has Schedule Update in Magento 2 Programmatically ?
I just need check if exists Schedule Update associated with a product.

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Comment: I have added the answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341300/how-to-get-all-scheduled-changes-for-a-product-in-magento-commerce